# JDBC cannot etablish a connection to jdbc:mysql://

Tags: mysql, jdbc, netbeans

so i've been trying to etablish jdbc connection from this host, but this what happens

[image]

Here's the error message:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://sinarkaryanusantara.com:3306/sinarkar_db_kasir?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Access denied for user 'user'@'address' (using password: YES))

Comment: Thanks for sharing your id and password on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to configure SSL to connect with other domain database.
without SSL you can only use localhost database with jdbc.

after configuration

use this to connect with database

```
jdbc:mysql://sinarkaryanusantara.com:3306/sinarkar_db_kasir?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true
```